# Помогите перенести Regexp c PHP на C#

Tags: php, c#, регулярные-выражения

PHP

```
preg_replace("/\^(.*?)\^/si", "<b>\\1</b>", $text);
```

Нужно реализовать на C#.
Пробовал так:

```
_title = Regex.Replace(_title, "^(.*?)^", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Не получается.

Comment: Игнорирование регистра в этой регулярке лишнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
_title = Regex.Replace(_title, @"\^(.*?)\^", "<b>$1</b>",
                 RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Знаки `^` надо экранировать, а опции можно и так реализовать:

```
_title = Regex.Replace(_title, @"(?si)\^(.*?)\^", "<b>$1</b>");
                                 ^^^^^
```